# How to hide console log in jhipster

Tags: angular, spring-boot, console, jhipster

I have jhipster project and I want to hide console logs, I use angular, spring-boot

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your AppRoutingModule turn enableTracing to false:

```
{ useHash: true, enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED }
```

should be:

```
{ useHash: true, enableTracing: false }
```

Comment: I have the opposite case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312743/how-to-use-the-console-log-in-angular-8/58317837#58317837  Can you help me?