# How to use the console.log in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I used to have my console.log in Angular 6 to see the content of variables in the browser

```
      console.log('CONSOLOG: M:paginateVar & O: this.var : ', this.var);
```

... and I was happy with it, but now I'm starting to use Angular 8 and I get this error (when I npm start):

```
No type errors found
Version: typescript 3.4.5
Time: 2104ms
× ｢wdm｣:    1029 modules

ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.ts
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):

D:\JHipster\spingular\src\main\webapp\app\home\home.component.ts
105:7  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

How can I see the content of a variable back in the browser?

TSLINT:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": ["node_modules/codelyzer"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": [false, "debug", "info", "time", "timeEnd", "trace" ],
    "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "jhi", "camelCase"],
    "component-selector": [true, "element", "jhi", "kebab-case"],
    "no-inputs-metadata-property": true,
    "no-outputs-metadata-property": true,
    "no-host-metadata-property": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-lifecycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": false,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a linting rule that you need to modify, not angular. 
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-console/ 
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

Comment: Even if you shut off the lint rule like folks will suggest, seeing console spam in a production release is atrocious. I'd recommend either stripping them on production build from the main.ts if `environment.production` = true, or at least wrap them in [isDevMode](https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an ESLint rule in Node.js.

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

The reason it's disabled:

> console is used
>   to output information to the user and so is not strictly used for
>   debugging purposes. If you are developing for Node.js then you most
>   likely do not want this rule enabled.

You may like to consider a logger: https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger

However, if you really just want to allow console.log you can edit the rules to set:

> "no-console": "off",

Comment: I pasted the tslint.json config on the question because it does not work like that or even including the "off". Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: TSLint was deprecated, therefore this answer is not valid anymore.

`no-console` is caused by [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) and its [rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-console/):

> **Rule: no-console**
>
> Bans the use of specified console methods.

Check your *tslint.json*:

```
"no-console": [
  true,
  "debug",
  "info",
  "time",
  "timeEnd",
  "trace"
],
```

Just change `true` to `false`.

Comment: Now I can print: console.log(this.var); but not console.log('CONSOLOG: VAR: ', this.frontpageconfigs);  Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Looks fine. Maybe `this.frontpageconfigs` is undefined?

Comment: No, it works when I use console.log(this.frontpageconfigs); but not with the text 'CONSOL LOG'. May be there is a change with the ' or "  . Thanks

Comment: Mmh. Not sure. Do you have `"no-console": [false]` in your _tslint.json_? And check your settings in your developer tools within your browser.

Comment: The terminal sent the error so it is the same on everybrowser. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

when in yours.TS file you can use console.log function.

Example :

```
 int id = 1 ; // id is declared variable 
 console.log ("id ", this.id ); // function called
```

while running the project, inspect element console  and you'll see that " id  1" will be printed

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, read the question carefully and then the other anwsers. You will see that your point is already covered. Thanks for your input. You will get better.